# PredicateBuilder and n+1 query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, predicatebuilder

I use `PredicateBuilder` to pass a Dynamic Expression to a method in my repository that uses it within `Where` clause. Here is the relevant repository code:

```
        var results = context.Set<T>().AsExpandable.Where(where);


        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            results = results.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return results.ToList();
```

In my controller I have this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Account>();
if (amount> 0)
    predicate = predicate.And(d => d.Amount <= amount);


var model = AccountRepository.Get(predicate, "Owner").ToList();
return PartialView(model);
```

When I make a reference to a property of "Owner" it makes another roundtrip to the database, causing an n+1 query problem. Is there any workaround to avoid this?

Comment: Seems that Owner property is lazy loading. Can you update your question with Accound code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the includes **before** the AsExpandable like so:

```
var results = context.Set<T>()

foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    results = results.Include(includeProperty);
}

return results.AsExpandable.Where(where).ToList();
```

Comment: Thx a lot, the only thing that need change its that the context.Set<T>() returns DbQuery<T> in wich i cannot call .Include, i end up with putting var results = context.Set<T>().Where(where); and then return results.AsExpandable().ToList();